# Automate editing of 100+ Hex Strings

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, hex-editor

I'm currently working on a project which involves me having to replace hundreds of Hex strings, so far I've been doing this manually but the data we have has grown too large to make this sustainable.

I was looking for a way to automate the process but none of the solutions I've found have been successful for me, most only provide a one-string-at-a-time approach solution, which is no quicker than Find & Replace in a Hex Editor.

An example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
Orange to Tomato

1) 4f72616e6765 to 546f6d61746f

Mango to Melon

2) 4D616E676F to 4D656C6F6E
```

This process needs to repeat for lots of data, Orange to Tomato, Mango to Melon, etc.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Look-up tables?

Comment: Are these hundreds of replacements done to the same file?

Comment: Yes, all of these replacements are done to the same file.

I have found ways of doing this but each method only allows for one value to be replaced at a time.

file.data
Find: OldlValue
Replace: NewValue

One of the greatest issues I face is that the file itself changes on a monthly basis, and the data shifts.

Answer (score 2):

You could save in a .json file which old strings should be replaced by which new strings. For example, so:

```
{"Orange":"Tomato","Mango":"Melon", ...}
```

Then you write a python program (or a program of your choice) that reads in the .json file and replaces all occurrences of old strings with the new one in your hex string file. Here you could use regular expressions. Of course you have to convert the strings from the .json file into a hex format first. I would estimate writing such a program takes about half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as a PowerShell script, but writing it is not that simple.

You would need to create a file containing pairs of hex strings,
containing search & replace,
then loop on executing the replacement.

This code fragment will help in the task, written for one
search/replace combo:

```
[byte[]] $searchBytes = 0x0, 0x80, 0x0  ## example
[byte[]] $replaceBytes = 0x87, 0xCE, 0xEB  ## example

[byte[]] $content = [System.Io.File]::ReadAllBytes( <filename> )

if( $content.Contains( $searchBytes ) )
{
    $startIndex = $content.IndexOf( $searchBytes )
    Write-Host "Found $searchBytes at $startIndex"
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $searchBytes.Length; $i++ )
    {
        $content[ $i + $startIndex ] = $replaceBytes[ $i ]
    }
}

[System.Io.File]::WriteAllBytes( <filename>, $content )
```